# What property says that $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} g'w' dx = 0$ for $w \in H_0^1(x_1,x_2)$, since $g$ is linear?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What property says that $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} g'w' dx = 0$$ for $w \in H_0^1(x_1,x_2)$, **since** $g(x)$ is linear?

$w$ is in $H_0^1(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$g'$ is constant, so $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} g'w'~dx = g'\int_{x_1}^{x_2}w'~dx = g' (w(x_2)-w(x_1)) = 0.$$